# React/Redux: Add timestamp to everything returned by a reducer to detect updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am constantly writing long conditions in componentDidUpdate to do things when new/different data arrives from the database, sometimes resorting to lodash to compare large objects. Random example from file I happen to be looking at:

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   // If there are messages, and they are different, clear replyFormPosition build new message tree.
   if (messages.length > 0 && !_.isEqual(messages, prevProps.discussion.messages)) {
     ...
   }
 }
```

I do this so much that the fact that there is not already a way to respond to changes to a "piece" of state returned by a reducer (unless there is) makes me think I am doing something wrong.

One way to simplify my long `if(prevProps...!==... && ..)` conditions in cDU would be to wrap each reducer in a function that adds timestamp: Date.now() to its response. Then I could just do

```
 if (prevProps.statePiece.timestamp !== props.statePiece.timestamp) {
   this.doSomethingWithUpdatedData()
 }
```

My first question: where would the object be that I wrap? Maybe the reducers that I pass to `combineReducers`?

```
 export default combineReducers({
   auth: addTimestamp(authReducer),
   discussion: addTimestamp(discussionReducer),
   group: addTimestamp(groupReducer),
   notifications: addTimestamp(notificationReducer),
   ...
 });
```

But more importantly, my second question: Why am I the only one who has this problem? It makes me think I am doing something wrong. Is there a simpler way to do things in response to new data from the DB?

Thanks! Let me know if I was unclear.

Comment: You should probably be decomposing your object as you pass it down the chain. That's not always possible, but it often is. If that's not possible, your timestamp idea probably won't help since it really only tells you that something, somewhere in the object has changed - at the very least, you would wind up rerendering everything that has a dependency on the object with every change, which would be very slow

Comment: Which chain? I'm not sure what you mean. In the example above, I want to create a new "message tree" (to nest replies etc.) when messages arrive. I can't check for `if (!!messages.length)`, because sometimes that piece of state will be full of messages from a previous page, or maybe the user posts a new message so I'm looking for changes. Usually I find myself checking for whether an object has changed.

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering where the `pieceOfStateDidUpdate` hook is!

Comment: For clarification, by `messages.length`, do you mean `this.props.messages.length`? I would say that the reducer for a `messages` component should retrieve a list of messages not an object in the shape `{discussion: [ << messages >> ]}`. As long as you're using a good key for your messages you wouldn't need the guard in the `componentDidUpdate` logic.

Comment: Yes ... :thinking: maybe I'm not using enough reducers, and my store state has too much nesting. Still though, I'd need to do something only when prevMessages !== messages, in this example

Comment: does your discussion component include the notifications or is notifications a separate component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185521/discussion-between-nth-chile-and-ic3b3rg).

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `combineReducers` with this function:

```
function(state = {}, action = {}) {
  return {
    // Add the action type at the top level
    actionType: action.type,

    // Add the reducers
    discussion: discussionReducer(state.discussion, action),
    group: groupReducer(state.group, action),
    itemHistory: itemHistoryReducer(state.itemHistory, action),
    ...
  }
}
```

It made it easier to, for example, redirect when a form was submitted:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.actionType === "UPSERT_RESOURCE_ITEM") {
    this.props.history.push(`some URL`);
  }

  ...
}
```